Get IP Address list with cidr range using java & java.net library
I am trying to fetch all IP lists with in CIDR range using JAVA. I got one sample code, but I am not sure it's working fine for all scenarios or not. Using java.net package.
public static List<String> getIPsInCIDR(String cidrRange) {
        List<String> ips = new ArrayList<>();
        
        try {
            // Split the CIDR range into IP and prefix length
            String[] parts = cidrRange.split("/");
            String ip = parts[0];
            int prefix = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
            
            // Calculate the number of addresses in the range
            int numAddresses = (int) Math.pow(2, (32 - prefix));
            
            // Convert the IP address to a byte array
            byte[] ipBytes = InetAddress.getByName(ip).getAddress();
            
            // Convert the byte array to an integer
            int ipAddress = 0;
            for (byte b : ipBytes) {
                ipAddress = (ipAddress << 8) | (b & 0xFF);
            }
            
            // Generate the list of IP addresses within the range
            for (int i = 0; i < numAddresses; i++) {
                int currentIP = ipAddress + i;
                
                // Convert the integer back to a byte array
                byte[] currentIPBytes = new byte[4];
                for (int j = 3; j >= 0; j--) {
                    currentIPBytes[j] = (byte) (currentIP & 0xFF);
                    currentIP >>= 8;
                }
                
                // Create InetAddress object from the byte array
                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(currentIPBytes);
                
                // Add IP address to the list
                ips.add(address.getHostAddress());
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return ips;
    }

Could you please check this and confirm. I tried this is works fine

Did this resolve your concerns?

You have a problem with using InetAddress to get the bytes.
The last value of the dotted quad format will be interpreted as an 8, 16, or 24 bit quantity depending on how the prefix is specified.  For example, 192.154.23 will be interpreted as 192.154.0.23 since 23 is treated as a 16 bit value and returned with 23 in the low order byte.  This is causing your IP addresses to be incorrectly computed. So when you increment the IP address your increment starts with the last octet specified in the address.  In the above example, that would be 23.
Also, keep in mind that if any part of the dotted quad is within the CIDR prefix range will be ignored as it will be encompassed by the mask.  For example,
192.158.122.22/25
192.158.122.99/25
192.158.122.49/25

will all have the same mask of 255.255.255.128 and will return the same range of 192.158.122.0 thru 192.158.122.127.
